# how to select single field from _id embedded field mongodb

Tags: python, mongoexport

Is there a way to select only **userId** field from **_id** embedded document?

I tried with below query

And also i wants to delete all the documents that comes as output to the below query may be in a batch of 10000 per batch by keeping database load and this operation should not hamper the database. please suggest.

Sample Data:

```
 "_id" : {
        "Path" : 0,
        "TriggerName" : "T1",
        "userId" : NumberLong(231),
        "Date" : "02/09/2017",
        "OfferType" : "NOOFFER"
    },
    "OfferCount" : NumberLong(0),
    "OfferName" : "NoOffer",
    "trgtm" : NumberLong("1486623660308"),
    "trgtype" : "PREDEFINED",
    "desktopTop-normal" : NumberLong(1)
```

query:

```
 mongo --eval 'db.l.find({"_id.Date": {"$lt" : "03/09/2017"}},{"_id.userId":1}).limit(1).forEach(printjson)
```

output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Path" : 0,
        "TriggerName" : "T1",
        "userId" : NumberLong(231),
        "Date" : "02/09/2017",
        "OfferType" : "NOOFFER"
    }
```

Comment: Anyone who can help with this??? Is it really possible to get a single field from embedded _id filed as shown above.